# distinct id from current month to previous month & missing id from previous month to current month

Tags: sql, postgresql

I am trying to get the distinct ID's from current month compared to previous month and distinct missing ID's from previous month to current month. I have a table, where i have two fields namely, snapshotname and assetsrcsysid. I have loaded this with sample data for 201901, 201902 and 201812. Ideally, I have this data going back to 201401, but for trials i am doing this with 3 months of data.

Please suggest how I can get this query improved such that it includes all months going back to 201401.

I have used below query to get the snapshotname, incoming_sysid( which are new in current month that are not present in previous month) and outgoing_sysid( which are missing from previous month in current month) as below. I ran this query using PostgreSQL on windows 7 64 bit platform.

```
WITH incoming AS
  (SELECT snapshotname,
          count(DISTINCT assetsrcsysid) AS incoming_sysid
   FROM public.sampleassetsrcsysid
   WHERE snapshotname = '201901'
     AND assetsrcsysid NOT IN
       (SELECT assetsrcsysid
        FROM public.sampleassetsrcsysid
        WHERE snapshotname = '201812' )
   GROUP BY snapshotname),

     outgoing AS
  (SELECT snapshotname,
          count(DISTINCT assetsrcsysid) AS outgoing_sysid
   FROM public.sampleassetsrcsysid
   WHERE snapshotname = '201812'
     AND assetsrcsysid NOT IN
       (SELECT assetsrcsysid
        FROM public.sampleassetsrcsysid
        WHERE snapshotname = '201901' )
   GROUP BY snapshotname)

SELECT incoming.snapshotname,
       incoming.incoming_sysid,
       outgoing.outgoing_sysid
FROM incoming,
     outgoing
WHERE 1=1;
```

expected results:

```
snapshotname  incoming_sysid  outgoing_sysid
201902          4               3
201901          3               5
```

Dummy Data:

```
snapshotname    assetsrcsysid
201901  s1
201901  s2
201901  s3
201901  s4
201901  s5
201901  s6
201901  s15
201812  s1
201812  s2
201812  s3
201812  s4
201812  s7
201812  s9
201812  s10
201812  s11
201812  s12
201902  s1
201902  s2
201902  s3
201902  s13
201902  s17
201902  s19
201902  s20
201902  s5
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NKNAL.png)

Comment: Let's say an assetsrcsysid exists for the first time in 201801, then not in 201802 and not in 201803, but again in 201804. Is this possible or can an assetsrcsysid that disappeared never reappear? If it can reappear: Would I count it as incoming for 201804, because it didn't exist in 201803? Or would I not count it, because it exists in some previous month (201801 in my example)?

Comment: Another question: If an assetsrcsysid only exists in one month, I count it both as incoming and outgoing for that month, correct?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming I understand your problem correctly, I would take a completely different approach, using window functions.  This starts with two things:

- A single record for each `snapshotname` and `assetsrcsysid`, which makes it easier to use window functions.
- An enumeration of the periods, so they are simply numbers.

Then we can use `lead()` and `lag()` to determine if a given `assetsrcsysid` is in the next or previous month, greatly simplifying the query:

```
with s as (
      select s.*,
             dense_rank() over (order by snapshotname) as snapshotname_index
      from (select distinct snapshotname, assetsrcsysid
            from public.sampleassetsrcsysid s
           ) s
     )
select snapshotname,
       sum( (prev_snapshotname_index = snapshotname_index - 1)::int ) as num_incoming,
       sum( (next_snapshotname_index = snapshotname_index + 1)::int ) as num_outcoming
from (select s.*,
             lag(snapshotname_index) over (partition by assetsrcsysid order by assetsrcsysid) as prev_snapshotname_index,
             lead(snapshotname_index) over (partition by assetsrcsysid order by assetsrcsysid) as next_snapshotname_index
      from s
     ) s
group by snapshotname
order by snapshotname;
```

Comment: I appreciate your quick response on this. I got what are you are saying but seems like, the way how the query is framed, I unable to get the expected result. I tried tweaking the lead and lag windows functions here. Let me just add the sample data for 3 months ( 201902, 201901 & 201812) in my original post.